# How can I detect if IntelliJ IDEA has a specific project open?

Tags: bash, intellij-idea

I'm modifying an external tool that requires a specific IntelliJ IDEA project **not** be open when it runs. Right now, users have to remember to manually close the project before running. I do detect if IntelliJ IDEA is running and warn users but I would really like to check if the specific project is open. I suspect there's some temp files or open files I could look for but I'm hoping some else has figured this out, and maybe a better, less fragile way.

Need Mac support but Windows support would be helpful if the solution has to platform specific.

-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lsof](http://ss64.com/osx/lsof.html) to check files opened by IntelliJ process.
You can use `ps` or `pgrep` to find IntelliJ PID.